# PHP-FPM and timeouts (503)

Tags: nginx, lamp, php

i've had some problem with my server running Nginx + PHP-FPM setup. This week our users have seen 503 after around 02.00 CEST. From browser it's timing out after a certain amount of time( over minutes of waiting). I've checked logs and the only thing i've noticed is the first line of the log below:

```
 [20-Sep-2013 01:45:00] WARNING: [pool web1] server reached pm.max_children setting (25), consider raising it
    [20-Sep-2013 01:45:03] NOTICE: [pool web1] child 3657 exited with code 0 after 30.161697 seconds from start
    [20-Sep-2013 01:45:03] NOTICE: [pool web1] child 3672 started
    [20-Sep-2013 01:45:07] NOTICE: [pool web1] child 3655 exited with code 0 after 33.749738 seconds from start
```

While it was timing out, i checked memory usage and count per process and PHP-FPM seemingly had 26 process running.

A restart of PHP-FPM helped. Here is the FPM log right after restart:

```
[20-Sep-2013 07:28:41] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[20-Sep-2013 07:28:41] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[20-Sep-2013 07:30:09] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1905
[20-Sep-2013 07:30:09] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[20-Sep-2013 07:30:13] WARNING: [pool web1] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 0 idle, and 10 total children
[20-Sep-2013 07:30:14] WARNING: [pool web1] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 16 children, there are 0 idle, and 12 total children
[20-Sep-2013 07:31:10] WARNING: [pool web1] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 0 idle, and 12 total children
[20-Sep-2013 07:31:11] WARNING: [pool web1] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 16 children, there are 0 idle, and 14 total children
[20-Sep-2013 07:31:12] WARNING: [pool web1] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 16 total children
[20-Sep-2013 07:31:13] WARNING: [pool web1] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 18 total children
[20-Sep-2013 07:31:14] WARNING: [pool web1] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 20 total children
[20-Sep-2013 07:32:27] NOTICE: [pool web1] child 2079 exited with code 0 after 73.199058 seconds from start
[20-Sep-2013 07:32:27] NOTICE: [pool web1] child 2099 started
[20-Sep-2013 07:32:29] NOTICE: [pool web1] child 2080 exited with code 0 after 74.523488 seconds from start
[20-Sep-2013 07:32:29] NOTICE: [pool web1] child 2100 started
```

Server info:
    KVM guest - Centos 6.4 x64 with current kernel.
    PHP 5.4.20
    nginx/1.3.14
    RAM 6GiB

```
Here is my FPM pool config:

    [web1]
    listen = /var/run/php-fpm/$pool.sock
    user = $pool
    group = $pool
    pm = dynamic
    pm=static

    pm.max_children = 25
    pm.start_servers = 5
    pm.min_spare_servers = 2
    pm.max_spare_servers = 5
    pm.max_requests =  100


    slowlog = /var/log/php-fpm/$pool-slow.log
    php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/$pool-error.log
    php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
    php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 1000M
    php_admin_value[upload_max_filesize] = 2000M
    php_admin_value[post_max_size] = 2000M
    php_admin_value[max_file_uploads] = 1000
    php_admin_value[max_execution_time] = 1200
    php_admin_value[session.gc_maxlifetime] = 86400
    php_admin_value[max_input_time] = 1200
    request_terminate_timeout = 14400s
    rlimit_files = 131072
    chdir = /

    listen.backlog = 16384
    pm.status_path = /status
    env[TMP] =  /var/www/vhosts/$pool/tmp
    env[TMPDIR] = /var/www/vhosts/$pool/tmp
    env[TEMP] =  /var/www/vhosts/$pool/tmp
```

Is this a matter of server unable to handle the traffic? I have long timouts due to the fact that server offers file up and downloads.
Also, i'm not sure if this is the problem as i've seen this before as well without server timing out. I've been reading around here to find similar issues/question and in fact some part of my FPM config is taken from recommended settings from here :)

Any insight into my issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: After you restart PHP-FPM how much time your website runs fine? Also, how much traffic do you have?

Answer (score 0):

First off you cannot have more than one PM setting set at one time, you currently have two.

In you're case I would try using the `pm = dynamic` option.

Then try these settings and see if it helps any:

```
pm.max_children = 25
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 3
pm.max_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_requests = 0
```

If you are not using any CHROOT then disable the `chdir = /`

Also I would use "recommended settings" very loosely. As with FPM there really are not "recommended" settings due to the fact that every server spec is going to be different and so is the load for which each server is going to have.

Comment: That was a mistake i did from copy & paste.  pm=static was commented out.Current settings use  pm = dynamic. I did the changes recommended by you and reloaded PHP-FPM. Immediately i'm starting to see:    [pool web1] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 0 idle, and 11 total children
WARNING: [pool web1] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 16 children, there are 0 idle, and 14 total children. Yes, you are right that i need to find a good config server load.